# How to add constraints to items with random positions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an ios app that I add a variable number (between 2 and 10) labels to in randomly generated positions. It's all done programmatically. This is how the location of the labels is determined.

```
int width = self.view.frame.size.width - 200;
int height = self.view.frame.size.height - 200;
newFrame.origin.x = arc4random() % width;
newFrame.origin.y = 80 + arc4random() % (height-80);
```

All of the labels are added to an array, `self.viewLabels`, after they are created and added to the view, otherwise there's no permanent reference to them because they are created in a loop

```
while (numViews < (numLabels)){

        CustomLabel *timer = [[CustomLabel alloc] init];;
        ....
```

It works fine, except when I turn the app to landscape view. Some of the labels disappear that were at the bottom of the portrait view. I'm looking into adding constraints programmatically, and I understand the first step is to add the elements that need to be constrained to this dictionary

```
     NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button, button2);
```

Since I only have reference to these labels in the array `self.viewLabels`, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can get the labels in that dictionary. I tried to use the iterator to create unique names for the labels

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [self.viewLabels count]; i++){
        CustomLabel * label[i] = self.viewLabels[i];

    }
```

That doesn't work, and even if it did, I can't figure out how to add them to the dictionary. And even if I got them in a dictionary, how to add constraints to items that have random positions in the view?

Can you suggest a strategy I could use in this situation?

**Update**

If it's impossible to add constraints after I've randomly generated positions, is it possible to do something when I create the positions to ensure they will all be visible in both landscape and portrait?

Update 2- based on the first answer by @rdelmar, I've tried the code below (i.e. adding labels without frames and then adding constraints after they are added to the view). However none of the labels are appearing on screen. You can see how my code was before by the lines I've commented out. I had previously added labels in random locations...

```
    while (numViews < (numLabels)){

        CustomLabel *label = [[CustomLabel alloc] init];;

//        
//        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50);   //removed the frame
        label.text =  @"blah";


//        newFrame = label.frame;
//        int width = self.view.frame.size.width - 200;
//        int height = self.view.frame.size.height - 200;
//        newFrame.origin.x = arc4random() % width;
//        newFrame.origin.y = 80 + arc4random() % (height-80);
//        label.frame = newFrame;
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50]];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
        tgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tgr.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [label addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

        label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [self.gameClocks addObject: label];
        numViews += 1;

        [self.view addConstraint:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                     multiplier:1
                                       constant:0]];
        [self.view addConstraint:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     multiplier:1
                                       constant:0]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try thinking about this in a different way -- you don't add constraints to views with randomly generated positions, you create random constraints that result in the views having random positions. So, when you create the views, you don't give them any frame. You create the label, add it to the subview, then add the constraints. If you want the labels to be visible in both portrait and landscape, it would be best to use the multiplier rather than the constant values of the constraints so the position is relative to the size of the view (not a constant distance from some edge). To do this, you would use constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:, rather than the visual format language, so you don't have to worry about the views dictionary. When you use the multiplier, you have to use the right edge or the bottom edge of the superview, since those have non-zero values (while the top and left side do not).

After Edit:

This is one way to do it. I create random locations by passing in a random number between 0 and 1 to the multiplier coefficient. To keep the labels inside the view, I pin either the label's left side or right side depending on whether the multiplier value would result in the label being close to the left side or right side of the superview (same with top or bottom). I am also making the height and width of the label relative to the size of the view, so the labels are shorter but wider in landscape.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *labelArray;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.labelArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    while (self.labelArray.count <10) {
        UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [self.labelArray addObject:label];
        [self createConstraintsForRanomPositions:label];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< self.labelArray.count; i++) {
        [self.labelArray[i] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label %d", i]];
    }
}


-(void)createConstraintsForRanomPositions:(UIView *) view {
    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    CGFloat rightMultiplier = arc4random_uniform(100)/ 100.0;
    CGFloat bottomMultiplier = arc4random_uniform(100)/ 100.0;

    NSLayoutConstraint *con1;
    if (bottomMultiplier <= .2) {
        con1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:bottomMultiplier constant:0];
    }else{
        con1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:bottomMultiplier constant:0];
    }

     NSLayoutConstraint *con2;
    if (rightMultiplier <= .2) {
        con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:rightMultiplier constant:0];
    }else{
        con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:rightMultiplier constant:0];
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint *con3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:.2 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:.1 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[con1, con2, con3, con4]];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // this is needed, otherwise the frames are all {{0,0}, {0,0}} in the following forloop

    for (UIView *placedView in self.labelArray) { // rejects any label that overlaps with any other
        if (![placedView isEqual:view] && CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(view.frame, -2, -2), placedView.frame)) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            [self.labelArray removeObject:view];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried to follow your instructions. You can see what I came up with in the update in the OP. I added the labels without any frame at all to the subview, set `[label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` for each label and then called that method you referred me to. None of the labels are showing on screen. I'm pretty sure I'm using the method incorrectly. I added the constraint to `self.view` and then referred to the label in the section `constraintWithItem:label`. Not sure if I should add constraints in the loop after everything added . Can you help?

Comment: I also had no idea how to  `create random constraints` in that method, so I chose some oft used parameters first just to see if I could get the labels visible, and that didn't even work. Appreciate your feedback. Thanks

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil, well, you're constraints are not sufficient (no x or y positions), and you made your labels the size of the whole screen. As far as creating random constraints, the principle is no different that creating random frames -- you generate a random number, but use it for the multiplier and/or constant values in the constraints. I've updated my answer to show how I would do it.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a closer look. In your initial answer, you said when I create the views "not to give them any frame" so I removed this line `label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50);` from the code. Since I don't specify any size, is that why you said "you made your labels the size of the whole screen." I note that you don't give them a size either in your answer, unless `[UILabel new]`gives them a default size (documentation doesn't say). I'll try your code in a bit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil, no, [UILabel new] doesn't create any size. You gave them the size of the whole view by setting the width constraint of the label to be equal to the width of the superview (same with the height). I set my sizes the same way, but I'm setting the width and height to .2 and .1 times the width and height of the superview.

Comment: thanks for the info. Some of the labels occasionally appear too high (i can see the orange through the navigation controller bar, sometimes they're totally offscreen). Not sure what to adjust to fix that. Can you suggest? Sometimes they also overlap--to make it less likely they intersect I changed these values to -5 `CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(view.frame, -2, -2)`

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil, strange that you should see overlap, I never saw any after many tests. I've also never seen them totally offscreen. Sometimes they're right on the edge. You could change the condition (bottomMultiplier <= .2) to use a slightly bigger number or size the labels differently. Are you using my code exactly as I posted?

Comment: yes, it's about 99% as posted. In fact, I'm trying it over and over again, and logging the subviews as well as labelArray count, and I've noticed that at times when a label appears totally offscreen (i.e. invisible) the subviews and labelArray count is down by one, which seems to suggest that it's actually not offscreen but never got added or got removed. That's been confirmed multiple times. One little thing I changed was just to adjust to multipliers to make smaller labels. Instead of .2 and .1, I use .15 and .05

Comment: @delmar, ok, I've added a log statement to the loop at the end of `-(void)createConstraintsForRanomPositions:(UIView *) view ` and it only logs when the subview/labelArray count is down by one. That suggests that if there's a break out of that loop (i.e. for an intersection) the code isn't creating another view to replace it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51628/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-brainlikeadullpencil)